# Rails: DateTime helper for today, tomorrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

is there a `DateTime` helper in Rails (or a gem), that checks if a given `DateTime` is today, tomorrow... and produces outputs like `today, at 3pm`, `tomorrow, at 3pm` or `next Tuesday, at 3pm`?

I've found the `time_ago_in_words` helper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words but that's a different use case.

I can't find anything that formats a `DateTime` object like the examples from above. I found a solution for JavaScript (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/), and I'm searching for a similar one in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `DateTime` to `Time` this way : `your_date_time.to_time` and then use `time_ago_in_words`.

If you want a really specific way of displaying the date, you should create your own helper. Else, you can try to combinate `time_ago_in_words` with a custom helper.

PS: You also can edit the `time_ago_in_words` locales like that

```
"en":
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      about_x_hours:
        # The defaults are "about 1 hour" and "about %{count} hours"
        one: "1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
```

Full reference here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml#L18

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem you found, just convert DateTime to Time first

```
datetime = DateTime.now
time = datetime.to_time
#use time ago gem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for DateTime today as

```
DateTime.now.today? // returns boolean value if DateTime value is today's date
```

For tomorrow you can check as:

```
DateTime.tomorrow //will return tomorrow's date.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if I entirely understand what you are requesting but if you would like to set a time at 3pm today, you could write the following

```
DateTime.now.at_midday + 3.hours
```

What's great about the above code is that it sets time to a fixed point and lets you compute a relative time from it.

Here some more information from the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-at_midday)